# Dividir dos SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero dividir dos resultados de dos consultos MySQL

```
SELECT `count_first_recurrent`/`count_initialization` FROM
    SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) AS `count_first_recurrent`
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE (`orders`.`engagement` = 'R'
       AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'SE'),
    SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) AS `count_initialization`
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE (`orders`.`engagement` = 'M'
       AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'SE')
```

En efecto cada uno de los inner select devuelven numeros y quiero dividirlos.

Por desgracia lo que intenté me devuelve:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) AS `count_first_recurren' at line 3
```

## Actualizacion

Con lo que me aconseja Srsole, intenté:

```
SELECT (count_first_recurrent/count_initialization) FROM
    (
        (SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_first_recurrent
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'R'
           AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'SE') as a,
           
        (SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_initialization,
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'M'
           AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'SE') AS b
   )
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'M' AND `orders' at line 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en tu enunciado he hecho esto:

```
SELECT (count_first_recurrent/count_initialization) FROM
    ((SELECT 15 count_first_recurrent)as  a,
    (SELECT 3 count_initialization)as b)
```

Básicamente falta el tema de los paréntesis y poner alias a cada consulta.

---

**Actualización**

Te lo paso en limpio y con tu ejemplo

```
SELECT (count_first_recurrent/count_initialization) FROM
    (
        (SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_first_recurrent
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'R'
           AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'SE') as a,
           
        (SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_initialization
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'M'
           AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'SE') AS b
   )
```

Ten en cuenta que he puesto `count_first_recurrent` y `count_initialization` en el orden que  a mi ha parecido, cámbialo como convenga.

Tenia una coma de mas, esta borrada.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Ya lo intenté pero me parece que ha desplazado el problema

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica te faltan los alias de los campos

Comment: estoy viendo que te has liado con los parentesis

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica ya lo tienes

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Sin embargo me devuelve que hay un error de sintaxis cerca de  'FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'M' AND `orders' a la linea 8

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica a mi me funciona, lógicamente yo no tengo tu tablas son con unas propias. Puedes optar por ponerlo en el select sin los alias.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica sobra una coma despues de ```count_initialization```

Answer (score 0):

Otras formas similares de resolverlo:

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
       SUM(CASE WHEN engagement = 'R' THEN 1 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN engagement = 'M' THEN 1 END)
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT engagement, gxo_vads_subscription
      FROM orders
      WHERE engagement IN ('R', 'M') AND status = 2 AND gxo_means = 'SE') AS sq
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gxo_vads_subscription)
        FROM orders
        WHERE engagement = 'R' AND status = 2 AND gxo_means = 'SE') / 
        
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gxo_vads_subscription)
         FROM orders
         WHERE engagement = 'M' AND status = 2 AND gxo_means = 'SE')
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT SUM(count_first_recurrent) / SUM(count_initialization)
FROM (
      SELECT CASE WHEN engagement = 'R' THEN 1 END AS count_first_recurrent,
             CASE WHEN engagement = 'M' THEN 1 END AS count_initialization
      FROM orders
      WHERE engagement IN ('R', 'M') AND status = 2 AND gxo_means = 'SE'
      GROUP BY engagement, gxo_vads_subscription) AS sq
```