# Recuperar todas las líneas hijas cuya fecha es posterior a FECHA pero cuya línea padre también es posterior a FECHA

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla `orders` en MySQL 5.7 que representa el número de transacciones mensuales de los abonados. Quiero saber cuánto tiempo se quedan estas personas después de haberse comprometido una vez (Engagement) = M.

| Amount | Date | Engagement | Gxo Vads Subscription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.00 | 2021-06-24T01:10:00 | R | 20210523OMuQMB |
| 5.00 | 2021-05-25T01:10:00 | R | 20210523OMuQMB |
| 5.00 | 2021-05-23T14:14:35 | M | 20210523OMuQMB |
| 10.00 | 2021-06-01T03:27:17 | R | 20150430ETVFpg |
| 10.00 | 2021-05-01T03:28:44 | R | 20150430ETVFpg |
| 10.00 | 2021-04-01T03:27:18 | R | 20150430ETVFpg |
| 10.00 | 2021-03-01T03:25:37 | R | 20150430ETVFpg |
| 10.00 | 2021-02-01T03:24:53 | R | 20150430ETVFpg |
| 10.00 | 2021-01-30T14:44:10 | M | 20150430ETVFpg |

Quiero obtener el número de suscripciones distinctas donde Engagement = R después del 1 de marzo de 2021 y pero donde el compromiso inicial (Compromiso = M) es también después del 1 de marzo de 2021.

Entonces como ecuperar todas las líneas hijas cuya fecha es posterior a FECHA pero cuya línea padre también es posterior a FECHA?

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
SELECT (count_first_recurrent/count_initialization) FROM
    (
        # Contamos todas las segundas donaciones como count_first_recurrent
        # Estas deben ser las donaciones que se inicializan después de '2021-03-01 00:00:00.000'
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT orders_1.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_first_recurrent
        FROM `orders` AS orders_1
        INNER JOIN `orders` AS orders_2 ON orders_1.`gxo_vads_subscription` = orders_2.`gxo_vads_subscription`
        # Donde la transacción fue exitosa
        WHERE `orders_1`.`status` = 2
            # que es después de la campaña de Pascua
            AND `orders_1`.`engagement` = 'R' AND `orders_1`.`date` >= '2021-03-01' AND `orders_2`.`date` <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
            AND orders_2.`engagement` = 'M' AND `orders_2`.`date` >= '2021-03-01' AND `orders_2`.`date` <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
            ) as a,
        # Contamos todas las inicializaciones como count_initialization
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT orders_3.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_initialization
        FROM `orders` AS orders_3
        INNER JOIN `orders` AS orders_4 ON orders_3.`gxo_vads_subscription` = orders_4.`gxo_vads_subscription`
        # Contamos todas las inicializaciones como 
        WHERE orders_3.`status` = 2
            # que es después de la campaña de Pascua
            AND orders_3.`engagement` = 'M' AND orders_4.`date` >= '2021-03-01' AND orders_4.`date` <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
            ) as b
   )
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
0,28
```

Que es muy bajo

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c08c412249f694114456df703dfb693b)

Comment: A `orders AS orders_2 le falta un backtick, no?

Comment: Por otro lado, cuidado con la sensibilidad de nombres de tablas y columnas a las mayúsculas, generalmente en Windows es insensible, pero en un hosting Linux los errores no se harán esperar, a menos que tengas acceso al my.cnf. Para mayor portabilidad sugiero que esto siempre sea exacto.

Comment: Además del backtick faltante, tienes que usar el alias de la tabla en el SELECT (orders_1 u orders_2). Coincido con @aeportugal.

Comment: Cuando necesites plantear otra pregunta similar, en lugar de editar la misma te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta, sino las repsuestas van quedando desactualizadas, porque has cambiado la pregunta. También deberíás seleccionar en cada pregunta la respuestas que mejor responda la misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu query parece correcta, no lo puedo probar por que no te tengo tablas recursivas, pero lo que te falla es que usas el nombre de la tabla, cuando le has dado un alias.

Cambialo asi:

```
SELECT orders_1.Date AS `date`, orders_1.`engagement` AS `engagement`
FROM `orders` AS orders_1
LEFT JOIN orders AS orders_2 ON orders_1.`gxo_vads_subscription` = orders_2.`gxo_vads_subscription`
WHERE (`orders_1`.`status` = 2
   AND `orders_1`.`engagement` = 'R' AND `orders_1`.`date` >= '2021-03-01'
   AND orders_2.`engagement` = 'M' AND `orders_2`.`date` >= '2021-03-01')
```

Si no es lo que buscas, puedes hacer un `UNION`

que seria algo asi:

```
SELECT orders.Date AS `date`, orders.engagement AS `engagement`
FROM orders
WHERE `orders_1`.`status` = 2
   AND `orders_1`.`engagement` = 'R' 
   AND `orders_1`.`date` >= '2021-03-01'
UNION
SELECT orders.Date AS `date`, orders.engagement AS `engagement`
FROM orders
WHERE  orders_2.`engagement` = 'M' AND `orders_2`.`date` >= '2021-03-01'
```

Esta ultima no se si es lo que buscas exactamente, pero como te digo la solución al error de SQL es el primer ejemplo, por el motivo ya citado.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Sin embargo me gustaria contarlos pero no funciona.

Comment: En tu último intento me pregunto cómo consigues encontrar las suscripciones distinctas donde Engagement = R después del 1 de marzo de 2021 y pero donde el compromiso inicial (Compromiso = M) es también después del 1 Sin referencia a `gxo_vads_subscription`

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica no tiene sentido la frase "y pero", vamos al chat mejor?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126939/sql-srsole

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica quiza ya es tarde, pero lo tengo: ```select count(*), gxo_vads_subscription from orders o  where engagement = "R" and date > "2021/03/01" and gxo_vads_subscription in 
   (
       select o2.gxo_vads_subscription
       from orders o2
       where o2.engagement = "M" and o2.date > "2021/03/01"
    ) ```

Answer (score 1):

El requerimiento enunciado en la pregunta no coincide con la query posteada en la misma (En tu query haces una división, que en el enunciado nunca mencionas.).

Creo que está es la query que buscas (según el requerimiento escrito en el enunciado, no en tu query):

Es parecida a la query que posteaste en primer lugar.

En este caso vinculo con una subconsulta que trae las orders con status 2 y engagment M con fecha igual o superior a '2021-03-01', y luego de vincular restringo las orders con status 2 engagment M o R (Si solo seleccionas las orders con engagment R el resultado sería igual a que obteníás con la query original), y fecha igual o superior a '2021-03-01'.

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN (SELECT gxo_vads_subscription
            FROM orders
            WHERE status = 2 AND engagement = 'M' AND `date` >= '2021-03-01') AS sqom ON o.gxo_vads_subscription = sqom.gxo_vads_subscription 
WHERE o.status = 2 AND o.engagement  IN ('M', 'R') AND o.`date` >= '2021-03-01'
ORDER BY o.gxo_vads_subscription, o.`date`;
```

¿La query que posteaste en tu pregunta no está respondida en está otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/464691/218615)?. ¿Cual seríá la diferencia? Creo que modificandola un poco llegarías a la query que buscás.

Comment: Por eso quiero hacer un recuento 1. de la consulta que has hecho (Que muestra *cuentos de los compromisos que logran hacer pagamento recurrentes*) sobre 2. una consulta que no tenga en cuenta las filas en las que el engagement = R (*cuentos de las subscriptions en las que sólo había un compromiso y nunca un pago recurrente*). Por ejemplo en [este Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c08c412249f694114456df703dfb693b) deberiamos obtener 50%. Pero lo hizo sobre mi base de datos y 0.32% me parece muy bajo (estaba ~80% antes de '2021-03-01')

Comment: Quizás no estoy teniendo en cuenta los pagos que aún no han tenido tiempo de convertirse en recurrentes (pagos estan mensuales)

Comment: No entiendo bien que dato quierés obtener en el divisor (count_initialization), me parece que tiene allí el problema, te está retornando demasiadas filas.